# Navbar Toogle issue with Twitter Bootstrap 3 (subversion 3.0) on iPhone

Tags: html, css, iphone, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I recently built this website http://www.bier-in-aktion.at. When opening the site on iPhone 5/6 in Safari, the naviagation dropdown opening the first level to the anchor "Biergarten" works fine.
The problem appears, when I tab on "Biergarten", which should bring up the 10

of the dropdown-menu ul.

Also working fine on:
- Chrome/Browser Samsung Galaxy
- Mac Chrome
- Mac Safari

Do you have an idea how i can solve this iPhone issue?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">

<div class="container">

    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="http://www.bier-in-aktion.at/images/bier-in-aktion-logo.png" alt="Logo"></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a data-target="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Biergarten <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                                <li><a href="#Puntigamer">Puntigamer</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#Stiegl">Stiegl</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#Ottakringer">Ottakringer</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#Wieselburger">Wieselburger</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#Zipfer">Zipfer</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#Schwechater">Schwechater</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#Egger">Egger</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#G&ouml;sser">G&ouml;sser</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#Murauer">Murauer</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#Kaiser">Kaiser</a></li>
                 </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right beer-search-form" role="search">
            <h1 style="font-size: 1.4em; color: #c5c4c2; margin:0px; float:right">Aktuelle Bier Aktionen und Angebote</h1>
        </form>

    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
```

Many Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1):

a class="dropdown-toggle" need to add href tag here

need to add `href="#"` this will fix this.

Cheers.

Comment: Good catch...this is the second question I've seen this morning where the OP has removed the href from a dropdown toggle. I wonder why people are doing that.

Comment: i know ,right ?  maybe they think they dont need to link the <a> tag so they remove . ))